# Why didn't Sazed decrease his weight while running?

Tags: cosmere, mistborn

I read to the part where he decreased his weight to help him climbing a tree in order to observe the armies surrounding the capitol (second part of the second book). I made me wonder why didn't he decrease his weight to aid his speed. We all saw how a light build (like Vin) benefit from that.

And please no spoiler if you can help it.

Comment: I vaguely remember him drifting down into a basin by decreasing his weight as well, and if I remember correctly it was after the running part. So I assume he had only as much weight-changing stored up (or perhaps the metal "containing" weight was full) so that he needed all his resources for that one part. But it's been a while since I read, will go check the book out some time

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason he couldn't use a ironmind to store weight, but it wouldn't be a vast advantage, and he gets more out of using the speed in a steelmind directly.

Altering weight via feruchemy also seems to alter muscle mass by a relative amount.  This is why a full feruchemist like Sazed can't leap tall buildings in a single bound just like a Mistborn would.  So decreasing his weight might help speed him up a bit, but past a certain point would just make him floaty and uncoordinated.  Sazed also isn't a very physically trained fellow - he has more reliance on his mental feruchemy and using tinminds to put much time into optimizing the weight storage.

Aside from Sazed however...

> Other characters later in the series run a constant weight storage like you suggest, but mostly so there's a reserve of weight if they need to tap it.  The most it does for their regular physical ability is make them a bit more light on their feet.  More dramatic uses are possible, but the character that does so gets a lot of practice in it, for reasons that are even more spoilerish.

Comment: And also I recall, thinking himself a scholar, Sazed simply might not have thought of or considered ways he could have used his feruchemy physically to better avantage.  When he was fighting the Koloss in the Hero of Ages, he regretted never thinking of intentionally storing weight as he had never imagined it would be useful, and the only weight he had was merely a byproduct of his making himself occasionally lighter to take falls and such.

Comment: @Kai - did try to include that line of thought, but didn't remember that specific example, thank you.